# vb.net json.net deserialization issue

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I have an issue that is driving me nuts.  I have a project to deserialize and process a json response:

```
 [{"summary":[{"cardDate":"2013-08-06","cardId":46121,"contenderList":[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,10],"dateTime":"2013-08-06 10:36","marketList":["TOTE_WIN_PLACE","FORECAST","FORECAST_PLACE"],"raceId":465453,"raceNumber":2,"tote":"Australia","venue":"AU - Dog, Bendigo"}]
```

I have built classes to handle the response:

```
Public Class clsAXMeetList
    Public Property summary() As clsAXRaceList()
End Class
Public Class clsAXRaceList
    Public Property cardDate As String
    Public Property cardID As Integer
    Public Property [contenderList]() As clsAXContenderList()
    Public Property dateTime As String
    Public Property [marketList]() As clsAXMarketList()
    Public Property raceID As String
    Public Property raceNumber As Integer
    Public Property tote As String
    Public Property venue As String
End Class

Public Class clsAXContenderList
    Public Property runners() As Integer
End Class
Public Class clsAXMarketList
    Public Property [a] As String
    Public Property [b] As String
    Public Property [c] As String
End Class
```

but when the deserializer hits the first value in the contender list (1) it throws this error:

Error converting value 1 to type 'AsiaExchange.clsAXContenderList'. Path '[0].summary[0].contenderList[0]', line 1, position 71.

I have looked around and I cant find much help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `contenderList` is an array of numbers, not objects.  There is no conversion from numbers to arbitrary objects.  You need to either change your `contenderList` property to an array of integers (`Integer()`) or provide a converter to your object.  You will have to do the same for the `marketList` as well.

Comment: Perfect.  Worked first time; I thought both arrays were objects when they were just simple arrays.  I changed contenderlist to an array of integers, and marketList to an array of strings and it worked fine.  Much thanks and karma to you.